# How does one get an active instance of socket.io?

Tags: rest, sockets, socket.io, vue.js, vuex

```
io.on('connection', socket => { })
```

This snippet gives you instance 'socket', but I am currently in need of using that instance somewhere else in my project.

Is there a way of accessing it by the port it's running on or similar?

I am trying to change the state in Vuex (Vue.js) with Sockets, which I'd put into a handler in a REST Api.

Comment: Maybe you can just put the socket.io instance into vuex, so it will be accessible for all instances.

Answer (score 2):

As Reiner stated in his comment, you can try to save the socket into vuex itself in order to access it from all of your project. For example:

```
new Vue({
    ...
    created () {
        io.on('connection', socket => {
            this.$store.dispatch('SET_SOCKET', {
                getInstance () {
                    return socket
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

Don't forget to define the `'SET_SOCKET'` actions and mutations.

You will then be able to access it using `this.$store.state.socket.getInstance()`

I use `getInstance()` because if I remember correctly the socket mutates itself over time, and VueX does not like that.